# getting an error before loading data from Firestore in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

Here when i try to load data in my flutter app, before loading data it throws an error for 1 second then it displays the data, here is the error:
[image]

here is my code:

```
  class MapScreenState extends State<DashboardPage> {

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async*{
    var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance.collection('Profile').document(user.uid).snapshots();
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getData();//until this is completed user stays null we can use it to check whether it's loaded
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return new showProfile(
            name: "anonymous",
            email: "null",
            pin: "null",
            address: "null",
          );
        }else {
          var userDocument = snapshot.data;
          return new showProfile(
            name: userDocument['name'],
            email: userDocument["email"],
            pin: userDocument["pin"],
            address: userDocument["address"],
          );
        }

      },
    );
  }
}
```

How can i retrieve the data without showing the error?

Comment: Not a fix, but better to initialize stream to a variable and use it in `build` instead of invoking getData() inside `build`.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code there is a `Text` widget that is being given a string from firestore before the string is loaded. Try doing this:

```
...

Text(stringFromFirestore ?? ''),

...
```

In dart, the `??` operator checks if the first value (stringFromFirestore) is null, and if it is not, it returns the first value, but if it is, it returns the second value.